# jQuery getScript() - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

Tags: jquery, getscript

I am facing issues while using `getScript()` function,  here is my script

```
$.getScript("script.js").done(function(script, textStatus,jqxhr) {    
   console.log(jqxhr.status);
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
   console.log(jqxhr.status);
});
```

But i am getting the following error in the console..

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined, can you
>   please suggest the solution.  Actually i am using the getScript()
>   function to check whether the server is up/down.

Comment: In what version of jQuery ?

Comment: current jquery version is - v1.8.1

Comment: That's strange, and when you do `console.log( $ === jQuery )` you get true, right? There is no way jQuery doesn't return a promise from `getScript` regardless of what the filename is etc.

Comment: Works fine when testing -> **http://jsfiddle.net/c2n334nv/**

Comment: @John, right before calling `$.getScript()` try logging `$.fn.jquery` and double-check the version number -- something on your page may be including another version of jQuery.

Comment: Friends, i am really sorry about this, just now i have checked my jquery version number with jQuery.prototype.jquery, its showing "1.5.2" but in my project jquery.js file its showing v1.8.1.  So is there any way to fix this in "1.5.2" ?

Comment: @John: You can have multiple version of jQuery in a single page which will resolve your issue. Check this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: i cannot use multiple versions in my project, but is there a way that we can override the old getScript function from the latest jQuery lib ?